# Imaginary Capacitance and Imaginary Inductance interpretation and relations with circuit theory

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, capacitance, inductance

Today I came across with Complex **Capacitances** and **Inductances** for the first time:
$$L(j\omega)=L_{real}+jL_{imaginary}$$
$$C(j\omega)=C_{real}+jC_{imaginary}$$

So I started looking at their meaning and how they relate to the basic circuit theory that I've already learned. Let's start with the inductors.

### Inductors:

I found [this article](http://www.femm.info/dmeeker/pdf/chop2.pdf), that states (pages 7 and 8):

---

[image: Inductors - Article Part 1]
[image: Inductors - Article Part 2]

---

After that, I found that this "Power Loss" is associated with "Core Losses", like hysteresis losses, Eddy/Foucault current losses. So, my first question is:

- If \$L_{imaginary}<0\$, we have \$Power\space Loss >0\$, so we have a dissipation of energy by the magnetic core of the inductor due to (according to what the article says) eddy currents;
- If \$L_{imaginary}=0\$, we have \$Power\space Loss =0\$, so no eddy current and no energy dissipation;
- But, what if \$L_{imaginary}>0\$ ? Then we will have \$Power\space Loss <0\$, i. e., the magnetic core will supply power to the circuit! How is this possible? Or is the value of \$L_{imaginary}\$ somehow restricted by some equation, so that it cannot assume positive values?

(Another way to state this is considering the inductor impedance:$$Z_L=j\omega L=j\omega\cdot(L_r+jL_i\ )=-\omega L_i+j\omega L_r\ \ $$ The imaginary part of \$L\$ contributes to the real part of inductor impedance. This contribution is given in the form of a frequency dependent resistance \$-\omega L_i\$. So, if we have \$L_i>0\$ then \$-\omega L_i<0\$, a negative resistance!)

---

### Capacitors:

I found [this article](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/electrochemistry/75/8/75_8_649/_pdf). It states that (page 2) \$C_{imaginary}\$ is associated with dielectric loss.

---

[image: Capacitors - Article]

---

Another source states that this dielectric loss can be by Joule's heating effect, hysteresis losses and dielectric absorption. I guess we can model this dielectric loss in a analogous way to the losses in the inductor core:
$$Power\space Loss=-\frac\omega2 C_i v^2$$

Thus, a similar question arises:

- If \$C_{imaginary}<0\$, we have \$Power\space Loss >0\$, so we have a dissipation of energy by the dielectric;
- If \$C_{imaginary}=0\$, we have \$Power\space Loss =0\$, so no energy dissipation;
- But, what if \$C_{imaginary}>0\$ ? Then we will have \$Power\space Loss <0\$, i. e., the dielectric of the capacitor will supply power to the circuit! Again, how is this possible? Or is the value of \$C_{imaginary}\$ somehow restricted by some equation, so that it cannot assume positive values?

---

### Relations with basic circuit theory:

I've already learned that real circuit elements can be modeled using parasitic elements. For example, a real capacitor can be modeled like this:

[image]
                                                                 <sub>Image source: Wikipedia</sub>

My final questions are:

- The imaginary component of capacitance and inductance were used to "account losses" that occur in real components: hysteresis losses, Eddy/Foucault current losses, dielectric absorption ...
  Are all those losses counted using complex values also counted when we model a real component with parasitic elements?
- Which of the two models - using complex L and C or using parasitic elements - is the most accurate if we want a representation as close as possible to reality? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: Underlying these components is how they store energy and dissipate energy. For accurate prediction of behavior, you need to model the energy storage. The dissipative parasitics (ESR) of inductance and of capacitance are described in both the complex models and the parasitic models. Which is more important to you?

Comment: As I said in the question, I want to know what is the most accurate model - complex vs parasitic - if we want a representation as close as possible to reality. So you can assume that all losses are important.

Comment: Losses affect the energy storage, and cause internal heating; heating is what kills every electronic component; be aware of heating, strive for 10C above ambient at most. The non-dissipative parasitics cause localized **RINGING**, which produces non-certification of systems by the FCC because of excessive EMI electro magnetic interference.

Comment: It seems to me that the terminology used in the first reference is bizarre and incorrect. An **inductance** does not have a "real part", but an **inductor** may have a parasitic real **resistance**. And what is this "bearing"? Also, there is **no power loss** in a pure inductance or capacitance. I think you are mixing up a lot of different concepts.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, I know that there is no power loss in a pure inductance/capacitance. If I understood correctly, the ideia of the complex L and C is to **implicitly "incorporate the losses" of a real component into the imaginary part of the inductance/capacitance of an ideal component (that is zero without this "incorporation")**. So, when modeling a real inductor/capacitor, I don't need to draw parasite elements, because all of their effects (and others effects too, like core losses, dielectric losses...) are implicitly included in the imaginary part of L/C.

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, but that's what I understood.

Comment: I think you need to understand the behavior of the ideal inductance and capacitance before you start including "implicit" behavior. Otherwise you will be very confused. So what is this "bearing" mentioned in the first reference?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  The "bearing" is magnetic bearing. *"I think you need to understand the behavior of the ideal inductance and capacitance"*, what did I say wrong about this?

Comment: It bothers me that you never use the word "impedance", and that you seem to only consider parasitic effects that are frequency dependent. For example, the parasitic resistors in your capacitor model will obviously cause power loss that is not proportional to \$\omega\$.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The capacitor model was just an example. About impedance, I've already studied it. If we model the impedance of a inductor with complex inductance, we have: $$Z_L=j\omega L=j\omega\cdot(L_r+jL_i\ )=-\omega\ L_i+jωL_r  $$ So there is a resistance that is frequency dependent (\$-\omega L_i\$). Then, \$L_{imaginary}\$ contributes to the real part of inductor impedance. The problem is if \$L_{imaginary}>0\$ we have \$-\omega L_i<0\$, a negative resistance! This is another way of stating part of my fist question.

Comment: @ViniciusACP Have you identified any papers that discuss the ***basis*** for using a complex valued inductance and how that value is worked out? (I have. I'm just wondering if you have.) By the way, it is ***always*** negative. (And it is *never the same, twice*, so to speak.) There's a motivation for this approach, but if I had to guess (and I do) I'd say you haven't understood where and why it arrives in the paper you cite. The topic is too complex to present here, by the way. (No pun intended.)

Comment: @jonk No, I haven't. I did not find much information about complex L and C. If you want to share them with me, I'll be glad. So \$L_i\$
is always negative. [I didn't understand this: *And it is never the same, twice*; Could you clarify it for me, please?]. Another thing: so will \$C_i\$ be always negative too, or not?

Comment: @ViniciusACP If I were well-versed on the subject, I'd of course provide the seminal papers for you. I've found some that tell me enough about why and it has to do with modeling the Eddy Currents in a convenient mathematical way -- it's not physics, it's modeling with a parameter that cannot be directly coupled to a physical reality. It's just convenience. And it is different at different speeds for the same motor/whatever. So there's a lot of "fitting" going on, as well. Look up Kapjin Lee and Kyihwan Park and see about papers using FEM formulations, as well.

Comment: @ViniciusACP Euler's and complex notation can be quite useful for modeling anything that rotates or spirals or depends upon such behaviors in a plane. Just as quaternions may be useful for very compact modeling of continual rotation in three dimensions. In pure math, they are interesting of their own right. As they apply in reality, you have to keep some things in mind. (For example, devices are real-valued and yet electronics engineers use complex-valued voltages, currents, and impedances all the time.) \$e^{s=\sigma+j \omega}\$ is quite compact and easy to work with using Euler's.

Comment: @ViniciusACP Rather than papers, I did find a web site that may help a little. It includes a table of real and imaginary inductance values and it deals with a similar subject (I think.) It's [here](http://www.femm.info/wiki/inductionmotorexample).

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the references! I found Kapjin Lee and Kyihwan Park papers on IEEE Xplore.